# cannot convert from string to int

Tags: c#

i want to convert what i selected from the combobox so i can edit it or delete it, but the messege "cannot convert from string to int" keep showing

```
if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();
        string Query = "select * from tbl_article where NameArticle='"+comboBoxArt.Text+"'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, sqlCon);
        SqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                txtName.Text = myReader.GetString("NameArticle");
                txtPrice.Text = myReader.GetInt32("PriceArticle").ToString();
            }
        }
```

and also when i run it, the selected item changes to his id "IdArticle".
how can i fix this ??

Comment: what is the type of `PriceArticle` and `NameArticle` in the database?

Comment: instead of `GetString` or `GetInt32` you should use `GetValues`

Comment: NameArticle => varchar(50) and PriceArticle => int

Comment: @P.Pat now it says "cannot convert from string to object"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do this?

```
txtName.Text = myReader["NameArticle"].ToString();
txtPrice.Text = myReader["PriceArticle"].ToString();
```

It should get whatever value from database whether its `int` or `DateTime` etc then convert it to string?

Comment: still one thing, when i select an item from the combobox, the item switchs to his ID in the combobox

Comment: this is the best answer, it's easy to do a TryParse to the text later on if you need the value back as a number.  As to your second question, i don't understand it at all.

Comment: @AbdelJelilZaghouani that is due to your query `where NameArticle='"+comboBoxArt.Text+"'`. I suggest you start practicing parameterized query and also use `Add` instead of `AddWithValues`. [About Parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements) & [Why stop AddWithValues](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @ferday so, the combobox shows articles names from a table called tbl_article, the article have an id(IdArticle), a name(NameArticle) and a price(PriceArticle), when i select an article from the combobox, the name changes to the ID in the combobox